# PyOpenSSL set verify flags on OpenSSL.SSL.Context

Tags: openssl, pyopenssl

In `PyOpenSSL`, when verifying certificate chains offline, I can set **verify flags**:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # OpenSSL.Crypto # # # # # # # # # # #
    trusted_certs = X509Store()                                   # init Certificate store
    check.trusted_certs.set_flags(0x80000)                        # X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN
    int_cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, int_ca_cert_pem)
    check.trusted_certs.add_cert(int_cert)
```

This works.  *"It allow partial chains if at least one certificate is in trusted store"*.

When I create a real-connection to a server,  I cannot find an API to `set_flags`.  Am I missing an API?

```
# # # # # # # # # # # Socket # # # # # # # # # # #
sock = socket()
sock.setblocking(True)
sock.connect_ex(sock.getsockname())
des = (host, 443)
print('[*]Connect issued...')
sock.connect(des)
print('[*]connected: {0}\t{1}'.format(host, sock.getpeername()))

# # # # # # # # # # # Context # # # # # # # # # # #
context = Context(TLSv1_2_METHOD)
context.set_options(OP_NO_SSLv2 | OP_NO_SSLv3 | OP_NO_TLSv1)
ca_dir = Path(getcwd() + '/ca_files')
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=None, capath=ca_dir.__bytes__())
context.set_verify(VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb)

# # # # # # # # # # # Create TLS client  # # # # # # # # # # #
tls_client = Connection(context, sock)
tls_client.set_connect_state()                          

try:
    tls_client.do_handshake()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer.

```
context.get_cert_store().set_flags(0x80000)
```

Leaving this on SO for other people who hit the same issue with `PyOpenSSL` and `set_flags`.